# How does diffusion models "imagine" a new image from prompt?

Tags: diffusion-models, u-net, denoising-autoencoder

When a new image is generated through diffusion denoising, for instance:

[image]

I wonder if the resulting "Avocado Armchair" is purely using only those 2 images above it, or is drawing learned shapes from other previously trained images as well? In particular:

- The green texture color is similar to the first image. The chair shape is similar to the second image.
- But which part of the U-net autoencoder is capable to actually **"rotate this the chair and change its texture to green"**?
- Has the network seen this particular angled view of an armchair similar to image 2 somewhere during its training phase?
- Is it then merely replacing the texture of this angled chair (previously seen object shape with the same tag 'armchair'), segment this second chair and then replace its texture with the avocado green texture?

Any thoughts/comments are very welcome.